# Script that replace each repeated letter in a string with one letter

Tags: c++

I have a script which takes a word from input file and outputs customizated word in output file.

For example, in input file I have word `ccccccaaaaaannnnndlllllleeeee`and I need to edit the word it to look like candle and output in other file. So could you please give me a example of it?

So far I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string vards;
    std::ifstream input_file("virkne3.in");
    input_file >> vards;
    std::ofstream output_file("virkne3.out");
    output_file << vards.erase(std::unique(vards.begin(), vards.end()), vards.end());
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255, '\n');
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't have anything to do with your question. Also, please post what you've tried so far. We aren't going to write the program for you from scratch.

Comment: Also, please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: `So could you please give me a example of it?` candle

Comment: Your Q title and the actual Q are way-off.

Comment: What do you do for `ssssswwwiiimmmmmmiiiinng`? Or `aaaaaaarrrrrdddvarrrkkk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean *consecutive* repeated letters, `std::unique` does exactly that.

```
vards.erase(std::unique(vards.begin(), vards.end()), vards.end());
```

Comment: Got another q. why it doesn't take out word from virkne3.in file, it gives me error at line  input_file << vards; (no match for 'operator<<' in 'input_file << vards')

Comment: @Y2ok: `operator<<` is for output, you want `operator>>` for input

Comment: Ouch, didn't notice that. Ehmm, and if I insert your code like this - vards = your_code_here; it won't work too. any ideas?

Comment: @Y2ok: That's not necessary.  Re-read my answer, I fixed it so it modifies vards instead of my made up string str.  vards itself is reassigned in the code in my answer.

Comment: @Y2ok: the erase function doesn't return anything.  His code must be a line by itself.  After the line executes, vards will be holding the result.

Comment: @Y2ok: Right, what Duck said.  Put my code as a statement by itself, and then, in the next statement, print vards to the file.